# How to find the pattern and rate of change in a parameter for repeated measurement data

Tags: r, time-series, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I have data of Troponin (TRP) levels (a type of protein found in the muscles of heart) which are measured in more than 200 patients. The data is divided into  Placebo and Drug-X group. For every patient, the TRP levels are measured in Day 1, 3, 7, 14, 21 and 28. Incase the patient is discharged before 28 days, one extra measurement , i.e `TRP_on_discharge_day` is taken and that can in any day between 1-28. NOTE: not all the subjects have all the measurements as some patients get discharged in between.

I have two questions:

Firstly, I want to study the average TRP level in placebo and Drug-X group and whether they are significantly different. As data has multiple measurements for each subject, I think, a normal t test cannot be done. So as I read elsewhere, I am trying a linear mixed model using `lme4::lmer` function. And my model is `lmer( measurement ~ Randomization + (1|id))`. where `measurement` is the TRP level, `Randomization` is the group (Placebo or Drug-X) and `id` is the id of subject. Is this correct way to model my question?

Secondly I want to study the pattern and rate of change in TRP in Placebo group and Drug-X group and test whether they are different. Can you please give me some help on how to do this, what technique to use.

I am `dput`ing a sample data here.. any kind of help is highly appreciated.

```
structure(list(`Medication Code` = c(7001, 7004, 7008, 7009, 
7014, 7016, 7018, 7022, 7025, 7026, 7028, 7031, 7032, 7033, 7036, 
7038, 7039, 7044, 7045, 7052, 7055, 7057, 7066, 7068, 7079, 7081, 
7083, 7090, 7093, 7097, 7103, 7105, 7107, 7110, 7116, 7123, 7125, 
7129, 7132, 7133, 7135, 7136, 7142, 7143, 7144, 7146, 7150, 7151, 
7152, 7153, 7157, 7166, 7168, 7171, 7174, 7175, 7176, 7177, 7185, 
7186, 7189, 7192, 7195, 7197, 7200, 7202, 7004, 7008, 7010, 7018, 
7022, 7026, 7032, 7036, 7038, 7039, 7044, 7045, 7052, 7055, 7057, 
7066, 7081, 7097, 7116, 7123, 7125, 7132, 7133, 7135, 7142, 7143, 
7144, 7146, 7151, 7152, 7157, 7168, 7174, 7175, 7176, 7185, 7189, 
7195, 7198, 7202, 7009, 7018, 7022, 7026, 7028, 7038, 7052, 7081, 
7090, 7100, 7105, 7125, 7133, 7135, 7144, 7152, 7174, 7176, 7189, 
7038, 7066, 7116, 7133, 7135, 7133, 7135, 7135), Randomization = c("Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", 
"Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Drug-X", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", 
"Drug-X", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Drug-X", "Placebo", "Drug-X", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo"
), trp_day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("TRP_DAY0", 
"TRP_DAY3", "TRP_DAY7", "TRP_DAY14", "TRP_DAY21", "TRP_DAY28", 
"TRP_DAY35"), class = "factor"), measurement = c(4, 17, 20.5, 
2.05, 5, 7, 8, 3, 5, 5, 5, 34, 3, 8, 4, 7, 7, 12, 5, 10, 10, 
16, 2, 8, 4, 8, 11, 15, 24, 5, 4, 8, 0.025, 4, 7, 7, 3, 3, 8, 
11, 16.7, 3, 9, 2, 4, 3, 4, 8, 12.6, 0.014, 7, 3.5, 7, 9, 13, 
9, 14, 6, 4.2, 6, 9, 6, 11, 9, 5, 12, 4, 5.5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 4, 
5, 3, 3, 7, 5, 6, 6, 10, 4, 6, 6, 13, 7, 3, 6, 12, 7, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 7, 10, 9, 4, 7, 5, 7, 4.8, 29, 9, 0.02, 6, 0.03, 3, 3, 5, 
6, 5, 5, 9, 5, 3, 15.1, 4, 10, 27, 3, 6, 8, 10, 15, 17, 3, 29, 
38, 17, 11, 8, 10), id = c(7001, 7004, 7008, 7009, 7014, 7016, 
7018, 7022, 7025, 7026, 7028, 7031, 7032, 7033, 7036, 7038, 7039, 
7044, 7045, 7052, 7055, 7057, 7066, 7068, 7079, 7081, 7083, 7090, 
7093, 7097, 7103, 7105, 7107, 7110, 7116, 7123, 7125, 7129, 7132, 
7133, 7135, 7136, 7142, 7143, 7144, 7146, 7150, 7151, 7152, 7153, 
7157, 7166, 7168, 7171, 7174, 7175, 7176, 7177, 7185, 7186, 7189, 
7192, 7195, 7197, 7200, 7202, 7004, 7008, 7010, 7018, 7022, 7026, 
7032, 7036, 7038, 7039, 7044, 7045, 7052, 7055, 7057, 7066, 7081, 
7097, 7116, 7123, 7125, 7132, 7133, 7135, 7142, 7143, 7144, 7146, 
7151, 7152, 7157, 7168, 7174, 7175, 7176, 7185, 7189, 7195, 7198, 
7202, 7009, 7018, 7022, 7026, 7028, 7038, 7052, 7081, 7090, 7100, 
7105, 7125, 7133, 7135, 7144, 7152, 7174, 7176, 7189, 7038, 7066, 
7116, 7133, 7135, 7133, 7135, 7135)), row.names = c(NA, -133L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This looks like a “design or critique my understanding of my analysis for me sort of question”.  More suited for stats.stackexchange.com . After a proper design is described and the OP shows what efforts he has attempted, this may become a suitable SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question:

> I want to study the average TRP level in placebo and Drug-X group and whether they are significantly different.

...yes, the model:

```
lmer( measurement ~ Randomization + (1|id))
```

will provide an estimate of the difference between the two groups on average.

For the 2nd question:

> I want to study the pattern and rate of change in TRP in Placebo group and Drug-X group and test whether they are different.

... you need to incorporate the time variable and interact it with the group variable:

```
lmer( measurement ~ Randomization*trp_day + (1|id))
```

and this will provide an estimate the slope over time in each group.

In the first instance it will be a good idea to treat time as numeric, not a factor.

Comment: I was surprised to see no discussion of the structure of the data frame.

Comment: @IRTFM I don't see anything unusual with the data frame.....what did you think warranted discussion ?

Comment: Nothing wrong per se Two things deserved comment IMO. 1) the factor levels were properly  ordered, but it was not defined as an ordered factor. So your suggestion to make numeric might have been more emphatic and had a more expansive explanation. 2) The data was (correctly) in long format although not really an [MCVE[, since the repeated observations were so sparse that the code you suggested would probably have failed on that data example. Furthermore, The code suggested did not include a data parameter.

Comment: @IRTFM thanks for the input. Regarding 1)  the suggestion to use `as.numeric` was to make interpretation easier - if left as a factor there are a lot of estimates to interpret, (which can be good if there is a nonlinear association) 2) the data provided is only a sample so whether the code works is rather beside the point; however in this instance the code runs without problems on the sample.